# Java. Вероятность 5 процентов

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Подходит ли такой код для получения единицы с вероятностью 5 процентов?

```
int rand = (Math.random()<0.95)?0:1;
```

Comment: Да. Это классический способ дискретизации

Comment: Вы знаете, почему-то очень частые выигрыши) Не могу понять в чем дело. С 6 раза выпала единица, потом со 2, потом с 17 раза правда, но всеравно странно.  Сейчас протестирую на большом количестве.

Comment: Запускаете 1000 раз, считаете сколько выпало единиц и убеждаетесь, что их будет порядка 50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, такой код подходит. ***НО*** тут нужно учитывать, что числа, который возвращает `Math.random()`, не совсем случайные. Дело в том, что `Math.random()` возвращает так называемые ***псевдослучайные числа***. Это значит, что какие - то числа ***могут*** выпадать чаще, какие - то реже.

Нет, это не означает, что `Math.random()` возвращает неподходящие числа и то, что нужно срочно искать какую - то библиотеку для рандомизации. Не существует генератора, который возвращает абсолютно случайные числа. Это связано с тем, что для генерации случайных чисел нужен так называемый ***источник энтропии*** - нужно что - то ***беспорядочной***, ***хаотичной***. Компьютер ничего хаотичного не имеет.

Но есть исключение - [*random.org*](https://www.random.org/). Данный сайт генерирует абсолютно случайные числа используя ***атмосферный шум***.

Comment: У компьютера обычно есть аналоговый вход, младший бит оцифрованного сигнала для недорогих звуковых карт пляшет от тепловых шумов элементов.